# Python - List search repeats Not matched?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7, search

In this python program, I am trying to implement a search in a sorted list.

The problem I am facing is simple, but I have not able to fix it. I want to print the element, when the element is found and when it is not found, I want to print "Not Matched". But the problem is for every element it prints "Not Matched" if the **selected element == sorted_list[i]**. i don't want to get this. I want to get "Not matched" once if the element I am looking for is not in the list.

Here is the code.

```
for i in range(0, len(sorted_list)):
    if take_input == sorted_list[i]:
        print sorted_list[i]
    elif take_input != sorted_list[i]:
        print "Not Matched"
```

Comment: Did you know `for item in sorted_list:`? And also `if take_input in sorte_list:`?

Answer (score 1):

You  can use `for ... else ...` with `break` statement:

```
for i in range(0, len(sorted_list)):
    if take_input == sorted_list[i]:
        print sorted_list[i]
        break  # get out of the for loop.
else:
    # This will be executed only if the `for` loop is not terminated with `break`.
    print "Not Matched"
```

If you use [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in), you don't need to iterate it:

```
if take_input in sorted_list:
    print take_input
else:
    print "Not Matched"
```

BTW, instead of using indexes, just iterate the sequence if you don't need the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

use `in` to check if `take_input` is in the `sorted_list` and avoid the need to iterate over `sorted_list`:

```
if take_input in sorted_list:
    print take_input
else:
    print "Not Matched"
```

You don't need to to use range to iterate over `sorted_list` you can just use:

```
for  i in sorted_list:
    if  i == take_input
```

If you wanted the index you should use `enumerate`:

```
for ind, ele in enumerate(sorted_list): # ind is each index, ele each each element in the list
    if take_input == sorted_list[ind]:
```

Answer (score 0):

It could work this way. ( switches )

```
switch_found = 0

for i in range(0, len(sorted_list)):
    if take_input == sorted_list[i]:
        switch_found = 1
        break
# else it will continue 

if switch_found == 1:
    print sorted_list[i]
else:
    print "Not Matched"
```

This will make sure it prints the found element only once. If switch is not set to 1 that means the element is not present and "Not matched" will be printed ( once ).